# How to pass parameters when exec stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

This will work.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyName], [Country] FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Country] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>        
       <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Mexico" Name="Country" Type="String" />        
    </SelectParameters>
```

But this won't work. It will give "Incorrect syntax near '?'." error message.

```
SelectCommand="EXEC Docs.[DocumentList] @UserName = ?, @Service = ?, @YearGroup = ?, @Category = ?">
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="8882074" Name="UserName" />
   <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="9" Name="Service" />
   <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="YearGroup" />
   <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Category" />
</SelectParameters>
```

This doesn't work either.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListViewSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ *** %>" 
        SelectCommand="EXEC [Docs].[CategoryList]" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="8882074" Name="UserName" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="9" Name="Service" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Gives me this error. """Could not find stored procedure ''."""

But changing the selectcommand to this works fine.

```
    SelectCommand="EXEC [Docs].[CategoryList] @UserName = 8882074, @Service = 9"
```

So how do i pass parameters when executing stored procedure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a stored procedure, you should:

- set the `SelectCommand` to just the stored procedure name
- set the `SelectCommandType` to `SelectCommandType.StoredProcedure`

With this, all the usual parameter stuff works as before!

```
SelectCommand="Docs.[DocumentList]" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
```

**Update:** the `SelectCommand` should be **JUST** the stored proc name! No `EXEC` or anything else......

Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListViewSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ *** %>" 
    SelectCommand="[Docs].[CategoryList]"   **JUST THE STORED PROC NAME !!**
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="8882074" Name="UserName" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="9" Name="Service" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Hum? The stored procedure requried few parameters to be supplied. How do we supply those if we just put the name? Handcoding the value like this will work fine. **EXEC Docs.[DocumentList] (at)UserName = 122, (at)Service = 3, (at)YearGroup = 12, (at)Category = 1"** But i need to supply parameter dynamically.

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: you have the whole list of `<SelectParameter>` entries, no?? Those are the values that your stored proc expects, and that's how you send in the values...

Comment: Yes I do have <SelectParameter> entries. But i don't know how to link that to the stored procedure. I normally work with Sql and the first example on my first post, that is how i work with Sql. (at)Name=?. But when exec a stored procedure, it won't like **?** in it

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: as I said in my response - just define the stored procedure name as your `SelectCommand`, set the `SelectCommandType` to `StoredProcedure` and define a list of parameters....

Comment: still doesn't work Marc. I edited the post above, please help.

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: in your `SelectCommand`, you should have **JUST** the stored procedure name - **NO** `EXEC .....` or anything ....

Comment: WoW .......... it workssssssssss now :D 
Thanks so much that you explained me so patiently.